# can anyone please explain me the need for & in the first code snippet

Tags: c++

In the following snippet of code I have noticed ampersand is used even though we aren't manipulating the string. Can anyone please tell me why it's needed?

```
bool compare(string &s1,string &s2) 
{ 
    return s1.size() < s2.size(); 
}
```

Snippet 2: would this code work?

```
bool compare(string s1,string s2) 
{ 
    return s1.size() < s2.size(); 
}
```

Comment: Presumably the question is about [tag:c++]? Please tag correctly to attract the right answerers.

Comment: sure,would do next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` sign (reference) is needed, because this way the program will only use a reference to the original string. If you don't use a reference, then the program will copy the string, so the program will be

- A bit slower
- Less memory effective

A const reference (`const string&`) is even better, because it will make it read-only, so you can pass string literals. Like `compare("abc", "foo bar")`.

Yes, your second snippet would work, but it's not recommended.